# Slicing audio files using GET requests in Python on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, python-3.6

Trying to spin up a simple Flask app on Elastic Beanstalk for slicing audio in chunks.
First step to download the audio file using GET request:

```py
@application.route("/<path:url>", methods=['GET'])
def converting_audio_task(url):
    import requests
    r = requests.get(url)
    file_name = 'audio.wav'
    with open(file_name,'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
```

Audio files are hosted on GCP Storage using public URLs (I have this exact app running on GCE without issues):
`https://storage.googleapis.com/sampleaudio.appspot.com/audio.wav`

GET request fails with the following error

```
/var/log/httpd/error_log
-------------------------------------
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 390, in prepare_url
[Sat Nov 23 17:43:49.946393 2019] [:error] [pid 28537] [remote 118.109.93.79:4] raise InvalidURL("Invalid URL %r: No host supplied" % url)
[Sat Nov 23 17:43:49.946398 2019] [:error] [pid 28537] [remote 118.109.93.79:4] requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Invalid URL 'https:/storage.googleapis.com/sampleaudio.appspot.com/audio.wav': No host supplied
```

Notice that strangely disappeared slash after `https:` in the error message.
Adding or deleting slashes in the request could lead to errors like `requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: No schema supplied.`

I have no clue what could be wrong with this code for AWS but apparently I'm missing crucial something here.
Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@application.route("/<path:url>", methods=['GET'])
```

When you specify `path` here, you're actually referring to one of 5 [convertor types](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules).  I suspect the `path` convertor expects a UNIX like path, so is removing the double slashes.

A workaround for this would be to pass the 'storage API URL' as URL argument to flask instead:

So the request URL to your application would be:

```
http://localhost:5000/?url=https://storage.googleapis.com/sampleaudio.appspot.com/audio.wav
```

You'd then handle this in Python with:

```
@application.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def converting_audio_task():
    import requests
    url = request.args.get('url')

    if url:
        r = requests.get(url)
        file_name = 'audio.wav'
        with open(file_name,'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
        # eventually
        return 'success. Ingested URL: %s' % (url,) ,200
    else:
        return 'url arg missing', 404
```

With this method the url reaches the backend correctly.

It's worth noting that there are a few things wrong with this approach:

- The storage API URLs may end up in server logs, because it's part of the request URL string.  An alternative would be to POST the data.
- When you write to the file, you're writing to the disk of the app server.  I'm not sure if/how EB allocates this storage.  An alternative would be to write to an object store like S3, using the [`boto3` python client](https://github.com/boto/boto3).
- If you handle large audio files, the application will block whilst the track is downloaded from Google.  That means the client doesn't get a response until the blocking function (`requests.get` and the file write operation in this case) has completed.  A better explanation  of this and how to deal with that in Amazon's environment can be found in : [AWS Elastic Beanstalk Worker Environments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html).

Comment: Brilliant explanation! You have boosted up my recently started Python journey on so many levels!